# Is it possible to optimize images uploaded by Carrierwave gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In Rails, while using the carrierwave gem, can we optimize images that are being uploaded? Optimize means compress and shrink the file size?

Comment: It means , the quality of image you are uploading. You can pass in percentage.

Comment: Perfect. How can I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/jtescher/carrierwave-imageoptimizer, https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Specify-the-image-quality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You should write own image processor and use ImageMagick or MiniMagick command to optimize images as you wish.

For example [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ryzmaa/use-imagemagick-to-create-optimised-and-progressive-jpgs) is article about optimization of images with MiniMagick.

---

The second way is related to using such gems as [carrierwave-imageoptimizer](https://github.com/jtescher/carrierwave-imageoptimizer) it provide image optimization out of the box.